# Learning GNU GCC compiler optimization implementation

Tags: gcc, gnu

I would like to understand how the GNU GCC compiler handles optimizations. I know its not easy but I can't seem to find any GCC internal implementation details even just to get started.

Do I have to be a contributing GNU GCC developer to view the source code and know the low/high level design? Where can a developer, who wants to contribute to GCC, find the implementation details?

Comment: where have you looked? "open source" means the source is "open" for you to read and review regardless of who you are.

Comment: @msw I had been looking for the implementation details. Guess I just didn't look hard enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC is open source and its source code is freely available. You can even [browse it online](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/). And its internals are [documented](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/).

Comment: Had to wait for 4 minutes to accept this one as answer. SO doesn't trust me. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can download `gcc` from all over the place.  The best place to start might be the official page: http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html

A good place to read about the optimizations is in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc), which describes a lot of flags that control individual optimizations.